# How to Recursively Check Rows and Columns In A TicTacToe Program?

Tags: java, recursion

I am writing a TicTacToe program to check if X's or O's win.  First I had to use itteration to check, then I need to use recursion to check.  I can't figure the recursive code.  This is the code I have(so far) to check if a "X" or "O" has won

```
    public boolean horizontalCheck(String[][] board, int row, int col, String 
    {
        boolean same = false;
        if(col == 0 && board[row][col].equalsIgnoreCase(xo))
        {
            return horizontalCheck(board, row, col + 1, xo);
        }else if(col == 0 && !board[row][col].equalsIgnoreCase(xo))
        {
            same = false;
            return same;
        }else
        {
            return horizontalCheck(board, row, col - 1, xo);
        }
    }
```

Once I get this, I will be able to use it for the vertical wins and diagonal wins with a few modifications.

Comment: Why do you want to do it recursively?

Comment: @MichaelT its for a school assignment

Answer (score 0):

Go with a following code:

```
public boolean horizontalCheck(String[][] board, int row, int col, String xo)
    {
        if(col == -1) return true;
        if(board[row][col].equalsIgnoreCase(xo)){
          return horizontalCheck(board, row, col - 1, xo);
        }else{
          return false;
        }
    }
```

Call it with:

```
horizontalCheck(board, row, board[0].length, xo)
```

One liner will be :

```
public boolean horizontalCheck(String[][] board, int row, int col, String xo)
{
   return col == -1 ? true :
         board[row][col].equalsIgnoreCase(xo) ? 
                 horizontalCheck(board, row, col - 1, xo)
         : false;
}
```